# Interpreting matrices of SVD in practical applications

Tags: machine-learning, pca, svd

I have a question regarding the interpretation of the different matrices produced by singular value decomposition.

Suppose a mxn matrix $A$ containing n images of m pixels. So each column of this matrix when reshaped is an image. The images are actually wavelets transformations but that bears no relevance to the question. Furthermore, the first k columns of $A$ are images of dogs and the remaining columns are images of cats. So I have something like this:

```
wavelet_dc = np.hstack((wavelet_dogs, wavelet_cats))
U, S, V = svd(wavelet_dc, full_matrices=False)
```

What is the interpretation for U, S and V? I know we can build the original image based on a sum such as $A = \sum_{i} u_{i}s_{i}v^{T}_{i}$ in which $u_{i}$ and $v_{i}$ are column vectors of U and V, respectively. I also know that $S$ determines the most important modes of the original matrix and that the columns of U are the features associated to those modes. However, what role does V play in this matrix? I'd like to know how to think about V in practical applications (that is, more than as a rotation in the geometric interpretation of SVD)

Furthermore, suppose I plot V in the following way:

```
plot(V[0:40, 0], 'o-', markersize=3)
```

[image]

Since V is a nxn matrix, I don't know how to interpret it, but I think this code is actually taking the first 40 rows and the first column of V. As I understand V as:

$$V = \begin{pmatrix}v_{1}^{T} \\v_{2}^{T} \\\vdots \\v_{n}^{T}\end{pmatrix}$$

I think the plot is referring to the first component of the 40 vectors $v_{1} ... v_{40}$ but what does it mean? In the Coursera class "Computational Methods for Data Analysis", this is described as the dogs for the first mode and `V[0:40, 1]` would be the dogs for the second mode, and so on. You can see the notes [here](http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/compmethods/Lecture%20Note%20Packet/LectureNotePacketSciCompMeth.pdf), figure 159, page 388. This is assuming of course, that at least the first 40 columns of $A$ contained images of dogs. In the class, they also plot `V[80:120, 0]` because their matrix $A$ actually has the first 80 columns representing images of dogs and the last 80 columns representing images of cats, so `V[80:120, 0]` is plotting the first 40 images of cats.

UPDATE:

According to the video lectures, W8_L21_P3-Features: https://class.coursera.org/compmethods-002/lecture/76, they seem to interpret `V[0:40, x]` as the projection of the first 40 dogs onto the modes. Well, V has dimensions nxn which is the number of images, however, I wouldn't interpret it as "dogs". In any case, I think such projections shouldn't be `V[0:40, 0]` but `V[0, 0:40]` because these are the first 40 components of the vector $v_{1}^{T}$ that multiplies the first mode $s_{0}$. However, please let me know if I made a mistake.

Comment: If you can get your hands on the book/PDF `Understanding Complex Datasets:
Data Mining with Matrix Decompositions`, I would highly recommend that for interpreting SVD + other methods. I read it too long ago to recall the content though.

Comment: That book looks amazing. Thank you very much. I just glanced some relevant sections to this question, but I can't determine which interpretation fits the particular use given in the Coursera lecture. I will read more thoroughly tomorrow, though.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have an answer. If you notice a mistake, let me know.

One interpretation explained in the book suggested by Cam.Davidson.Pilon is the factor interpretation. This tells you that a matrix $A$ with n rows and m columns  can be decomposed into a matrix $C$ with $n$ rows and $r$ columns, a matrix $W$ with r rows and r columns and a matrix $F$ with $r$ rows and $m$ columns. So suppose that your matrix $A$ contains $n$ objects and m attributes. As a consequence of this decomposition, you can think of $C$ as a different view of the $n$ objects, except that instead of using $m$ pieces of information, you use r pieces of information (usually, $r < n$). Similarly, $F$ can be thought as a different view of the attributes of $A$, again using $r$ pieces instead of $n$.

This description applies to general decomposition. The difference in SVD is that the matrices $W$ and $F$ have $r=n$, but the same interpretation is possible.

Therefore, in the example I described in the question, the matrix $A$ looks like this:

$$
  A = \begin{pmatrix} 
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\\  
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\\  
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\\  
  a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & \cdots & a_{m,n}  \end{pmatrix} 
$$

in which the rows are attributes (in this case, pixels) and the columns are objects (dogs and cats). An SVD decomposition of this matrix would like this:

$$ A = U\Sigma V^{*} $$
$$ 
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
  u_{1,1} & u_{1,2} & \cdots & u_{1,n} \\\
  u_{2,1} & u_{2,2} & \cdots & u_{2,n} \\\ 
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\\  
  u_{m,1} & u_{m,2} & \cdots & u_{m,n}  
  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\\ 
  0 & \sigma_{2} & \cdots & 0 \\  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\\ 
  0 & 0 & \cdots & \sigma_{n}  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
  v_{1,1} & v_{1,2} & \cdots & v_{1,n} \\\
  v_{2,1} & v_{2,2} & \cdots & v_{2,n} \\\ 
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\\  
  v_{n,1} & v_{n,2} & \cdots & v_{n,n}  \end{pmatrix}
$$

Following this factor interpretation, every row of $V^{*}$ corresponds to a factor, the first columns correspond to dogs and the last ones to cats. So, let's take the first 40 columns of $V^{*}$ of the first factor. This should be:

```
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(V[0, 0:40], 'o-', markersize=3)
ax.set_xlabel('Dogs')
ax.set_title('Mode 1')
```

[image]

This plot describes the value of the first factor for the first 40 dogs. Since these values $v_{1,1}, ... v_{1,n}$ are going to be multiplied by $\sigma_{1}$, they are associated to the first mode:

$$\Sigma V^{*} =   
\begin{pmatrix} 
  \sigma_{1} v_{1,1} & \sigma_{1}v_{1,2} & \cdots & \sigma_{n} v_{1,n} \\\
  \sigma_{2} v_{2,1} & \sigma_{2}v_{2,2} & \cdots & \sigma_{2}v_{2,n} \\\ 
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\\  
  \sigma_{n}v_{n,1} & \sigma_{n}v_{n,2} & \cdots & \sigma_{n}v_{n,n}  
\end{pmatrix}$$

Likewise, `V[0, 40:80]` produces the first factor for the first 40 cats.

Don't read too much into the values because I used a low quality dataset just to reproduce this part of the course.